# How do I get equivalency of my degree in USA?

Tags: job-search, united-states, pakistan

I have just moved to USA from Pakistan.

I have BsCS(hons.) degree from Pakistan.

I also have verified/stamped my degree from [HEC](http://www.hec.edu/) and [MOFA](http://www.mofa.gov.pk/)

I want to get equivalency of my degree here.

What is the process?

Do I need to validate my stamp from Pakistan Consulate? If yes, how they do? and what documents I need for that? I don't see any useful information [on their site](http://www.embassyofpakistanusa.org/consa10.php)

And after doing that, I have to visit any university to get me equivalence?

**EDIT:**

I actually have 2 years of professional experience in Software development. I think that is enough to showcase my skills, I can provide employers links to my projects I have done,

I also work at [UpWork (freelancing platform)](http://www.upwork.com) and have done over 50 projects with 5/5 feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do to get an equivalency will not do you any good unless it is stamped by the authority that your prospect employers' background verification agency is using. As far as I know there is not a single entity who does this degree equivalency evaluations. I am also from across the big pond and held many titles in the US so far and no employer wanted to see a degree equivalency document. One or two sticklers wanted to see my transcripts, but other than that, all there happened was to contact my university and verify I actually graduated with the degree I said I did on my resume.

So, do not get hung up on equivalency matter too much. If it is needed at some point, you will be asked and directed about how to proceed for it. If you do it something on your own now, you will be wasting your time and money, more than likely, for nothing

Comment: You are right, I have 2 years of experience in software development too, so for an IT field, experience matters more that piece of papers(degrees), please see edits in my question

Comment: @Umair This answer is correct in my experience. The tech industry is used to international students. I work at a very large.corporation, and my team just interviewed sveral people with overseas degrees. Their interview performance, work experience, and code samples were far more important than the country they earned their degree in. We even interviewed one candidate from Nigeria, a country not well known for its tech sector, and it still didn't matter.

Comment: @skrrgwasme yeah thats also I am thinking about. Degree should not matter ... experience is the key, as I have 2 years of experience in-field and on UpWork as well ...

Comment: @Umair I think I know what you meant, but you should be careful of how you phrase it. The degree *does* matter a great deal, especially when you're just starting out. It needs to be in a relevant field (for the tech industry, anyway) and it needs to be from a "good" university (the definition of "good" will vary from one hiring manager to the next, but usually means some kind of accreditation). My point is only that the *country of origin* is generally unimportant.